# How can I click/target at a pseudo element with Selenium IDE for Chrome?

Tags: css, selenium, google-chrome, testing

I'm currently trying to click at a pseudo element of a search icon on a customers website. Sadly, I've found now way how to do this. I've started with trying to click the parent element with:

[image]

But this ends up in a timeout because the element can't be found (before element). The structure of the element is following:

```
<span id="et_search_icon">
    ::before
</span>
```

So is there any way to target the pseudo element within `Selenium IDE for Chrome`?

Comment: could your target be xpath="//*[contains(@id,"et_search_icon")]"

Comment: have you tried with `span#et_search_icon:before` css?